# Home made lens system for imaging 3mm wide object

Tags: magnification

I want to take a picture of a 3 x 3 mm object so that only the object is visible, i.e. it fills the whole image. I have a small machine vision camera with 5.2 x 3.9 mm sensor, and I want to make a lens system on my own so that I would be able to take a picture of my object. I have a bi-convex lens with \$f\$ = 50 mm and lens tube where I put the lens so that it is about 13 mm deep inside the tube.

Is the following calculation correct?

If I want to see only the object, it should fill the whole sensor so the magnification \$m\$= 3.9 mm / 3 mm = 1.3. Since magnification \$m = b\,/\,a\$, and the thin lens equation says
$${1\over a} + {1\over b} = {1\over f}\,,$$
by substituting \$b = ma\$, I get that \$a = f\left(1+{1\over m}\right)\$ and \$b = f\left(1+m\right)\$. Now I can calculate that \$a\$ = 88.46 mm and \$b\$ = 115 mm. Lens tube length would then be 88.46 mm + 115 mm = 203.46 mm. So by installing my lens tube to the camera and adjusting the lens position 88.46 mm from the object and camera position 115 mm from the lens, I should see my small object.

Is this correct? I am doubting myself and my calculations. I did the calculations carefully but I'm not sure about it after all.

Comment: You might make the question clearer by defining the 'lens to camera distance' as the 'lens to sensor distance'. That's the distance that matters. How far in front of the sensor the camera to lens connection is makes no difference at all (as long as it's behind the needed sensor to lens distance).

Answer (score 2):

I checked your math using a different approach. More years ago, than I care to remember, I needed to calculate the focal length needed to yield a specific magnification with a specific Object to Image distance. I calculated based on 1.3 magnification.
Lens 50mm  magnification 1.3
Object to Image 203.5mm
Lens to Image 115mm
Lens to Object 88.5mm

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there is no fixed lens in your camera, then your calculations are correct. Perhaps a bit "too" correct, in the sense that the thin-lens formula assumes a negligibly-thin lens. Your lens has some non-zero thickness, so the front and rear nodal points of the lens are non necessarily directly in the center of the lens. Thus, **don't rely too heavily on precise calculations** (certainly not down to 10 µm precision). Give yourself several millimeters of lens-to-camera adjustability.

Secondly, I don't understand why you want the lens tube to be the sum of rear focal and front focal distances? You don't need any lens tube in front of the lens optics, unless you're using the lens tube *itself* to determine your subject-to-lens distance. I wouldn't do that, unless that distance is separately adjustable from the lens-to-camera distance, and also allows for plenty of light to illuminate your subject.

At 1.3:1, you're in the macrophotography regime. When setting up macrophotography, it's generally easiest to adjust the lens-to-camera distance for *magnification* (i.e., to fill the sensor); and then move the entire lens & camera combination closer or further from the subject to set focus. (Alternately, you can move the subject closer to or further from the lens, to get the subject in focus).

Answer (score 0):

Well, 115/88.46 is 1.3, and 1/115 + 1/88.46 is about 1/50.  So that calculation is correct for producing an image on a naked sensor with a single lens.  The problem, however, is "I have a small machine vision camera".  Not a sensor.  That camera will have a lens of its own, presumably focusing at infinity.  You cannot do your calculation without knowing its focal length that would likely be about the distance between that lens and the sensor.

Comment: Machine vision cameras tend to be sold without lenses, so you can choose a lens according to your needs. I've bought a few - and generally built my own lens assemblies.